# ClickOnce application using SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to learn how to create a simple application using Visual Studio IDE in C#.

I wrote a little application that uses a local SQL Server database for reading and storing data. On my machine, the program seems to work normally, but when trying to install the application on client computer it seems unable to read from the database.

I've tried to include the following prerequisites to the publish properties but it doesn't work:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2
- SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB

Any ideas about the right way to do it?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Sql Server, as it's name implies, wants to be a _server_, and that means running all the time as a service using resources to cache data, even when there's no user around. Even the Express Edition (and LocalDB to a 
 lesser extent) does this. That doesn't go well on a desktop where the user might want those resources to do other things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  SQL Server Express LocalDB (SqlLocalDB.MSI) on the computer you are deploying your ClickOnce application to.

Selecting "SQL Server Express LocalDB" in the Prerequisites window and using "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site" should take care of that:

[image]

If you do that it should install the LocalDB for you and any database errors are more than likely resulting from connection string errors or leaving `Integrated Security` enabled.

You need to test on a target computer which does not have "SQL Server Express LocalDB" installed and verify that after the ClickOnce deployment it is installed. This will confirm that the problem is not the missing prerequisites but the database access issues...

Comment: Note if you originally installed it on the client's computer without this prerequisite checked an upgrade will not install it. You will need to uninstall the program and reinstall a newly published version for the prerequisite to install.